# What's the efficient way to create a safe variable scope in a PHP file that is beeing included?

Tags: php, include, scope

Here is a very simplified example of the setup:

## includes/form.php

```
$secret_var = 'Mind blowing secret';
return '<form></form>';
```

## page.php

```
echo include('includes/form.php'); // Notice the unusual way of including
echo $secret_var;
```

## Result

```
<form></form>
Mind blowing secret
```

As you see, I'm not returning `$secret_var`, but its still exposed!

#### What is the most efficient way to create a scope for all variables within that *includes/form.php*, so that they are automatically unset by PHP?

Ofcourse I know I can run `unset($secret_var);`, but there are lots of forms, with many variables each and different developers constantly changing them. On a long term this method will mean basically a 100% chance to bugs. I need to do it somehow automatic (like variables within a function), but in this case without use of a named function (a file may be included more than once). It is also the highest priority to leave the code inside **page.php** unmodified, as this will mean a lot of changes system wide.

Maybe I could use an Anonymous function or something? Would be nice not to harm the performance...

Comment: Then don't `include` like that ;-) Why is that apparently not an option?

Comment: +1 to delnan - I'm baffled myself as to why a normal form is taboo!

Comment: It was done on purpose of returning the generated HTML, instead of echo'ing it directly or creating a new variable inside each form.php. Because sometimes the reused form is first merged with other HTML and only then echo'ed. I hope I'm clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
echo include('includes/form.php'); // Notice the unusual way of including
echo $secret_var;
```

use

```
echo call_user_func(function(){
    // secret var's scope is only valid in this block...
    // while the return '<form></form>'; is... returned.
    include('includes/form.php');
});
echo $secret_var;
```

and see how it goes.

**PS**: <del>Don't `echo include`. It means `echo bool;`, not the return in it.</del>

**PPS**: *And you're not using includes properly, as they're meant to... but I'm not even gonna start with that.*

Comment: Yes! To leave page.php unchanged I can wrap everything inside includes/form.php in `call_user_func()` and voila! It works! Thank you. About your PS: Why does it work if it's incorrect? And how to do echo it properly then? Like this `echo (include('includes/form.php'));` ? About PPS: Any known downsides of it? or just uncommon?

Comment: @Alph.Dev `include()` is a function. What is in the file is executed but it returns a `bool` value itself. So you should not echo it. If it worked here, it's only because of the weird way you're using includes. It's not a good idea to put a `return` in an `include`. It's a 99% guaranteed way to have issues that are very hard to track later on as the code after the `include()` will not execute. `return`s go in functions. **returns do not go in includes. That's a hack, not the right way :)**

Comment: Did some more research on this topic. From the PHP manual [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
_"It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function."_ It sounds reliable enough. The only limitation seems to be with remote files, but we won't use them in this project.

Comment: *This is probably a newer thing.* I'm an old dog, once I learn a trick properly, I stick with it :) I used it with `require` and `return` broke the flow of the file that `required` it. But I don't do it as functions exist for that very reason. Declare a function or more in the include and use it. Like it's meant to. *There are many hacky/shady things you can do while programming, but you shouldn't.* --- **Mom, CAN I smoke? Yes you CAN , BUT you MAY NOT :)**

Comment: It may be the case that you didn't write the crappy include, but you have to deal with it.